# Efficiently and safely assigning unique IDs

Tags: c++, database, performance, unique

I am writing a database and I wish to assign every item of a specific type a unique ID (for internal data management purposes). However, the database is expected to run for a long (theoretically infinite) time and with a high turnover of entries (as in with entries being deleted and added on a regular basis).

If we model our unique ID as a `unsigned int`, and assume that there will always be less than `2^32 - 1` (we cannot use `0` as a unique ID) entries in the database, we could do something like the following:

```
void GenerateUniqueID( Object* pObj )
{
    static unsigned int iCurrUID = 1;
    pObj->SetUniqueID( iCurrUID++ );
}
```

However, this is fine until entries start getting removed and other ones added in their place, there may still be less than `2^32-1` entries, but we may overflow the `iCurrUID` and end up assigning "unique" IDs which already are being used.

One idea I had was to use a `std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max-1>` and then traversing that to find the first free unique ID, but this would have a high memory consumption and will take linear complexity to find a free unique ID, so I'm looking for a better method if one exists?

Thanks in advance!

---

I'm aware that changing the datatype to a 64-bit integer, instead of a 32-bit integer would resolve my problem; however, because I am working in the Win32 environment, and working with lists (with `DWORD_PTR` being 32-bits), I am looking for an alternative solution. Moreover, the data is sent over a network and I was trying to reduce bandwidth consumption by using a smaller size unique ID.

Comment: The simple solution is to use larger datatype for the id, like 64 bit values, or even larger (like IPv6 switched to 128 bit values for addresses, from 32 bits for IPv4).

Comment: I agree with Joachim Pileborg but am curious... are all of those items existing in the heap? or are they saved to disk? If so - it may be a better idea to store them file-system based and not into a binary file ( like sqllite does ) and use that to faster address them after "balanceing" them into correct folder structure, and by that making the id pretty much useless as the filepath is your unique id then. Oh all the basics you need to take care of ( balanced tree/cleanup ) makes me wonder why anyone wants to write a database from scratch

Comment: And do not recycle any ID

Comment: Given that many items per second, it's possible the disk subsystem won't keep up with the "high turnover of entries" since they translate into a potentially large number of random accesses.

Answer (score 6):

With an uint64_t (64bit), it would take you well, well over 100 years, even if you insert somewhere close to 100k entries per second.
Over 100 years, you should insert somewhere around 315,360,000,000,000 records (not taking into account leap years and leap seconds, etc). This number will fit into 49 bits.

How long to you anticipate that application to run?
Over 100 years?

This is the common thing database administrators do when they have an autoincrement field that apprpaches the 32bit limit. They change the value to the native 64bit type (or 128bit) for their DB system.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is how many entries can you have until you are
guaranteed that the first one is deleted.  And how often you
create new entries.  An `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to
have a maximum value of at least 2^64, about 1.8x10^19.  Even at
one creation per microsecond, this will last for a couple of
thousand centuries.  Realistically, you're not going to be able
to create entries that fast (since disk speed won't allow it),
and your program isn't going to run for hundreds of centuries
(because the hardware won't last that long).  If the unique id's
are for something disk based, you're safe using `unsigned long
long` for the id.

Otherwise, of course, generate as many bits as you think you
might need.  If you're really paranoid, it's trivial to use
a 256 bit unsigned integer, or even longer.  At some point,
you'll be fine even if every atom in the universe creates a new
entry every picosecond, until the end of the universe.  (But
realistically... `unsigned long long` should suffice.)